# How do I concisely typeset propositional proof trees?

Tags: trees, forest

I want to draw things like

[image]

and optionally

[image]

I don't need to typeset proof trees as in the second picture, but it would be nice to know how to typeset it if anyone could do it without a sweat. But, I want to be able to draw the first picture with or without numbers on the left.

I found https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244187/82730 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/242261/82730. But, the answers looked overly complex for a beginner. Also, I couldn't find `prooftree` package on CTAN.

Comment: For a TikZ solution look at the `child` action in the pgf manual (there is a whole section about trees) or the `forest` package which offers a convenient syntax. Have you tried something?

Comment: some other options: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/160325/need-help-with-making-logic-trees-in-qtree-tikz-qtree-i-e-aligning-numbering/233576#233576

Comment: `prooftree` package can be found in [cfr's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/244187/1952). Save this code in your working folder as `prooftree.sty` and test it.

Comment: @Bordaigorl I tried qtree and synttree. They all couldn't handle cramming multiple lines in one node. I will try others soon.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34850/discussion-between-cfr-and-crocket).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Updated as a later version is now on CTAN. Note that most images were created with the early code and the spacing is a bit squashed. The current spacing is shown in the image illustrating the use of cross-references in justifications. This is because closure symbols are now properly accounted for when the tree is packed.]

I would use **prooftrees**. It goes without saying that I am biased. On the other hand, I would have happily not written this package if I could have found one which did the job I wanted.

The package is based on **forest**.

The package is a wrapper for **forest**. You set up the tree like this:

```
...
\usepackage{prooftrees}
...
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    <preamble, if any>
  }
  <tree specification in forest's bracket notation>
\end{prooftree}
...
```

The preamble may be empty, but the argument is mandatory. That is, you can have

```
\begin{prooftree}{}
  <tree>
\end{prooftree}
```

but not

```
\begin{prooftree}
  <tree>
\end{prooftree}
```

By default, lines are numbered on the left and levels are grouped when no branching occurs. In terms of the tree, this means that no line is drawn to the parent when there is only one child.

Some additional styles are available within the tree:

```
checked
```

marks a premise or sub-conclusion as discharged. By default, a tick is used, but this can be customised if required.

```
close
```

closes the branch. By default, `\otimes` is used, but this can be customised.

This means that you can say

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees}% version 0.09
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}}
  }
  [P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), checked
    [\lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), checked
      [\lnot (P \land S) \lor R, checked
        [\lnot\lnot S
          [P
            [Q \lor \lnot R, checked
              [\lnot (P \land Q), checked
                [\lnot P, close]
                [\lnot Q
                  [Q, close]
                  [\lnot R
                    [\lnot (P \land S), checked
                      [\lnot P, close]
                      [\lnot S, close]
                    ]
                    [R, close]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [\lnot S, close]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

to produce

[image: proof tree]

To put the line numbers in brackets and remove the dot, just do

```
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
```

before drawing the tree

[image: customised line numbering]

Justifications for the inferences can be added using

```
just=<content>
```

For example

```
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}},
  }
  [P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), checked
    [\lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), checked
      [\lnot (P \land S) \lor R, checked
        [\lnot\lnot S
          [P, just=from 1
            [Q \lor \lnot R, checked, just=from 1
              [\lnot (P \land Q), checked, just=from 2
                [\lnot P, close, just=from 7]
                [\lnot Q
                  [Q, close]
                  [\lnot R, just=from 6
                    [\lnot (P \land S), checked, just=from 3
                      [\lnot P, close, just=from 10]
                      [\lnot S, close]
                    ]
                    [R, close]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [\lnot S, close]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
```

These are aligned on the right as the line numbers are aligned on the left.

[image: justifications]

Cross-references are also supported following a `:` in the argument of `just`. By default, these are set to the left of justifications (for use with rule names), but this can be switched as below. References may use either the `name` of the node or a relative node name. For example:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{prooftrees,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand*\linenumberstyle[1]{(#1)}
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}},
    just refs right
  }
  [P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), checked
    [\lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), checked
      [\lnot (P \land S) \lor R, checked
        [\lnot\lnot S
          [P, just=from:!r1
            [Q \lor \lnot R, checked, just=from:!r1, name=bert
              [\lnot (P \land Q), checked, just=from:!r11
                [\lnot P, close, just=from:!u]
                [\lnot Q
                  [Q, close]
                  [\lnot R, just=from:bert
                    [\lnot (P \land S), checked, just=from:!r111
                      [\lnot P, close, just=from:!u]
                      [\lnot S, close]
                    ]
                    [R, close]
                  ]
                ]
              ]
              [\lnot S, close]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: cross-referenced nodes]

The same system supports references in `close` if required.

```
to prove=<contents>
```

can be used in the preamble to provide a statement of the entailment or theorem to be proved. For example

```
\begin{prooftree}
  {
    close with={\ensuremath{\ast}},
    to prove={ \{P \land (Q \lor \lnot R), \lnot ((P \land Q) \land S), \lnot (P \land S) \lor R \} \sststile{L}{} \lnot S }
  }
...
```

produces

[image: proof statement]

It is also possible to move lines to later levels with or without justifications. Your samples don't seem to require these features, so they are not relevant here.